# How can I change the values of a class from another class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 classes, one of them being down below:

```
public class GenericEnemy : PoolObject{

   public string type;
   public float speed;
   public float maxHealth;
   public float enemyHP;
}
```

I want to use the variables of this class but I also want to alter their values when I want to have a new instance of this class. The second class I have mentioned will be the class that I will  instantiate this class in.

For Example:

One enemy prefab with this script will have a speed value of 10,

Another enemy prefab with this script will have a speed value of 5

I have tried using constructors but I don't know how I can make a constructor associated with that specific object. I apologize if I am missing something simple or this is straight up impossible. Thank you.

Comment: "variables" in classes are called "fields". However Properties have begun to replace fields for most uses | What you describe sounds like you have a factory pattern. | "I have tried using constructors but I don't know how I can make a constructor associated with that specific object. " Constructors are used when you create a instance using the new operator, which is the more classical way. But IIRC, Unity has a lot of Factory pattern methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are instantiating enemies as prefabs, you can directly add them to any generic data structure to later reference them

A list is easy to manage for starters.
You can take a look here

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/lists-and-dictionaries

For example

```
public List<GameObject> EnemyList = new List<GameObject>();
GameObject enemy = Instantiate(...);
EnemyList.Add(enemy);
```

Now you have all enemies referenced in a List can adjust the individual values in their components.
When the enemy is instantiated like this, you can use constructors to set the values, otherwise they'll be the default value you set earlier.

```
EnemyList[0].GetComponent<GenericEnemy().speed = 5f;
```

If you are directly creating enemies as prefabs, you can assign them in the Inspector by giving the list the [SerializeField] property, which will force it to be visible in the unity inspector. From there it is then a drag and drop.
This will reference the objects already present in the scene and they will retain any value you set manually.